# Why is the customer not being charged?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, stripe-payments, parse-cloud-code

I am trying to charge a customer using stripe, cloud code, and swift. I can successfully create a customer with all the metadata, but it fails when I charge the card. I get these errors. 
[image]

cloud code

```
var Stripe = require('stripe');
Stripe.initialize('sk_test_xxx');





Parse.Cloud.define("createCustomer", function(request, response) {
Stripe.Customers.create({
card:     request.params.coin,
account_balance: 25*100,
metadata: {
name: request.params.name,
customer: request.params.customer, // e.g PFUser object ID
}

}, {
success: function(customer) {
response.success(customer.id);
},
error: function(error) {
 response.error("Error:" +error);
}
})
    });


Parse.Cloud.define("createCharge", function(request, response) {
           Stripe.Charges.create({
amount: 100 * 25, 
currency: "usd",
card: request.params.coin,
customer: request.params.customerId
},{
success: function(httpResponse) {
response.success("Purchase made!");
},
error: function(httpResponse) {
    response.error(httpResponse)
    response.error("Uh oh, something went wrong");
    }
});

});
```

ios code:

```
                PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("createCustomer", withParameters: ["coin" : coin, "name": name, "customer": customer], block: { (success: AnyObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                    if error != nil {
                        print("create customer not working")
                        print(error)
                    }




                })

                var customerId = customer!

                PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("createCharge", withParameters: ["customerId" : customerId], block: { (success: AnyObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                    if error != nil {
                        print("not working")
                    }
                })
```

Comment: plz post also cloud code not as image.

Comment: Take a look at the Parse example project ["Parse Store"](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseStore), particularly the [main.js file](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseStore/blob/master/CloudTest/cloud/main.js)

Comment: I figured out what was wrong, but I don't know how to fix it. In the createCharge function I am trying to charge the customer which was created, but I am not using the right customer id, instead I am using the object id, where the stripe customer id is http://puu.sh/mtUae/5caca1fc81.png. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Write your cloud code like below. May be help it.

```
Stripe.Customers.create({

   //your key - value pair here which you want to pass.

}).then(function(httpResponse){

    console.log(httpResponse);
    response.success("success");

}, function(httpResponse){

    console.error(httpResponse);
    response.success("error");

});
```

Comment: This seems like it will create the customer, which I have already done, I am trying to charge them now.

Comment: @coolmac. you have return error msg 2 times. Because of that it raise an error. plz write only `response.error(httpResponse)` or  `response.error("Uh oh, something went wrong");`

Comment: why input parameter is only one shown i.e. customerID but you have pass 4 parameter as input.

Comment: I don't follow what you are saying.

Comment: I hardcoded the customer number provided by stripe and put that as the customer parameter in the charge function, and it works. How would I make it so it charges the customer it was just created.

Comment: May be you are getting nil value in customerId parameter in cloud code.

Comment: I got it to work. I just placed the Stripe.charges.create in the success block of the first function, at the end I just have one function that creates the user, and charges them.

Comment: what is exact issue?